# Where in WP can I check history or log of updates of plugins etc?

Tags: admin

I need to find out what happened at a certain time when some of my admins made some plugin updates etc. So I need to check in admin the log of changes, updates etc.

Where can I find that in WP admin?

Comment: I have never understood the lack of logged history in WordPress. The core needs something basic for developers to build on with a whole new category of plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pull it in wp-admin you actually have to go look at the plugin in wordpress repository and see if they added there or to the plugin author's site for a changelog.

That would be a nice feature for the future.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely. Maybe another table in db, but it can come handy in my opinion. At least for admins.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP asked for a log of plugin updates on _his_ Wordpress, not the plugin's changelog.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is the fix for you, but I was looking at a similar problem and I found this plugin. It seems to be updated regularly, so it might be a good contemporary solution:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/

> Keep an audit log of all changes and under the hood WordPress activity to ensure productivity and thwart possible WordPress hacker attacks

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution to log updates into a csv with timestamp and basic update info. Needs a writable `log/upgrader_process_complete.csv` file and you can use it with `(new Log())->setHooks();`.

```
<?php declare( strict_types=1 );

class Log
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public function setHooks()
    {
        add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', [$this, 'action_upgrader_process_complete'], 10, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * This function runs when WordPress completes its upgrade process
     * It iterates through each plugin updated to see if ours is included
     * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/61062331
     *
     * @param array $upgrader_object
     * @param array $options
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function action_upgrader_process_complete( $upgrader_object, $options ): void
    {
        $file = __DIR__.'/log/upgrader_process_complete.csv';
        $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s').', '.json_encode($options, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."\n";
        file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [different options](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/audit-log/).

I used several in the past and my go-to plugin now is **WP Admin Audit**.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-audit/

You can track all things happening around your site, including admin actions related to plugins:
[image: WP Admin Audit - Sensors (for WordPress activity log)]

It records who installed/updated which plugin at which time.